# Should I use docker in wordpress production?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, performance, docker

My question is, is it a good idea to use docker for a big woocommerce website (more than 100k products)? Or will this incur a noticable performance cost compared to running wordpress straight on the VPS (without containerization)?

Comment: You need to ask your question in a way that you can mark an answer as factually correct for all people with that question, this seems more like a discussion.

Comment: Otherwise, there are lots of huge sites built around containerised hosting, what you're asking does not have a simple strict yes/no answer

Comment: @TomJNowel I rephrashed the question so that somebody can provide a simple answer as "yes, it is a good idea" or "no, it isn't a good idea"

Comment: I don't think either is the answer, tbh it just doesn't make that much of a difference wether you use it or not, it isn't as important as you might think. The choice to use or not use docker is not in the top 100 considerations of a WP sites performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is it a good idea to use docker for a big woocommerce website (more than 100k products)? Or will this incur a noticable performance cost compared to running wordpress straight on the VPS (without containerization)?

**It won't make much difference, nothing you will notice.** It's not even in the top 50 things you should be concerned with for performance.

> running wordpress straight on the VPS (without containerization)?

A VPS doesn't run on bare metal, the V stands for Virtual, so it'll either be a Virtual Machine, or a container of some sort.

At 100k+ items of content, I would be more concerned with avoiding problematic queries and setting up object cache, perhaps some varnish style equivalent.